# Need precisely 3 digits after decimal point

Tags: c#

I want my function to return value with precisely 3 decimal places. I have tried following code:

```
public static double ToS(this double value)
    {
        double ToS = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.000}", value));
        return ToS;
    }
```

It cuts the value if it's longer than 3 decimal places but if the value is shorter it stay the same

Comment: You're returning a `double`. That's just the value - it's not a *formatted* value. If you really want a string representation with 3 digits, return the string instead. You *could* potentially use `decimal` which can preserve trailing insignificant zeroes due to the representation it uses, but `double` can't - there's no different `double` value for 0.500 vs 0.5, for example.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that you would need trailing zeros is for displaying the number, at which time you can convert it to a string with trailing zeroes to show in the UI. Are you doing this for some other reason than displaying the number in a UI? What is the root problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

To display a string with 3 decimals you do the following

```
var text = x.ToString("F3");
```

But to round a value to 3 decimals you do

```
var y = Math.Round(x, 3);
```

Note that mathematically `x=5` and `x=5.000` are the same number. So the request to store *a number* with three digits is non-sensical. The best you can do is display a string representation of a number.

Answer (score -4):

You can try either of this

```
public static double ToS(this double value)
{
   return Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.###}", value));
}
```

or

```
 return Math.Round(value,3);
```

See : [Math.Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_)

Comment: What does that return for an input of 0.5?

Comment: use Math.Round(value, 3)

Comment: @Stanislav: How does that help with the OP's actual question? They want a value with *exactly* 3 digits after the decimal point to be returned - so somehow a double value of "0.500" for an input of 0.5. That's impossible, as the `double` representation isn't designed like that. The question *can't* be answered without changing the result type.

Comment: you are right in this case, you should use formatting, but division and multiplication will not help either, but method return double

Comment: @JonSkeet - If he need 3 decimal places and for 0.5, it will be always 0.5. He needs then , as you mentioned , to return that as a string. My answer will help only if  decimal places has 4 or more figures.

Comment: @AmitRanjan your answer provides nothing new that are not already in the question itself.

Comment: @AmitRanjan: Look at the last sentence in the question. The OP's code already works for values with more than 3 digits after the decimal point. The whole question is about values like 0.5.